# C++ Concurrency, Coroutines & Job Scheduling?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++20

I'm trying to get my head around multithreading in C++, to come up with a general purpose implementation that suits me. Everyone has a different implementation, [Awesome CPP](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#concurrency) lists 39 libraries. It seems to me though that this is a logistical problem that is of the same ilk as any logistical scheduling problem in any field.

In my head, there are two obvious ways to repeatedly perform the job `abc`:

1. Split `abc` into 3 separate tasks: `a`, `b` & `c`. Spawn x threads. Have a queue. Jobs coming in get added to the queue. Each thread grabs the next task from the queue, and at the end of the task puts it back into the queue for the next task. They can either access the queue directly, or they can all communicate with a central 'manager' or 'scheduler' thread that serves them with their tasks.
2. Perform `abc` sequentially on x separate threads independently (parallelism.)

(1) has the problem that there is potentially a lot of overhead in keeping a queue and dealing with race conditions on it. (1) is otherwise intuitive and makes sense to me. It's what I would do in real life with a real life problem. It's literally how companies work in the real world.

(2) has the problem that any blocking causes the whole thread to block, idling the CPU thread. And (2) is far less flexible and applicable in less use-cases. On the plus side is has no overhead between tasks.

**Question 1:** Doesn't (1) also have the same blocking problem? If a thread reads from a file, it'll have to wait for the disk. How is that usually addressed, is there some way to yield back temporarily while its doing something like reading or writing from disk, or is this usually addressed simply by having more threads running than there are CPU threads and hoping not too many block at once?

It seems to me that (1) is clearly the better solution, except that it restricts the tasks only to medium to large scaled tasks. It would be pointless to use it to do something like parallelizing straightforward math (just an example) because handling the queue would take longer than the actual processing of the task. Hence the value of (1) for any given task is inversely proportionate to the difference between the overhead of the storage mechanism (the queue) and the size of the task. This sounds fine on the surface, until you realize that the efficiency of splitting into tasks is itself proportionate to the size of the task. To put it simply: you want each task to be small for overall efficiency in theory, but in practice you want each task to be larger so as to minimize the overhead of the queue.

Its obvious that some storage mechanism *is* required because you can't keep track of something without a recording mechanism, it doesn't have to be strictly a queue, but any form of recording the task in memory while it waits to be picked up. The optimization of the queue (I'm using the word loosely, not strictly a queue type) *is* then the #1 important factor here. The *cheaper* a task can receive its payload, the better.

Which leads me to **Question 2:** is this what C++20 coroutines are useful for? I've spent hours reading tutorials on coroutines, but it's still unclear what useful they're for. I think I get what they *do*. If I have it right they allow a special type of function (coroutine) to pause itself in the middle, yield its processing back to the caller along with a payload, and the caller can later resume it. But why would I want to do that? And can't I do that just by splitting the function into two?

**Question 3:** Are coroutines meant to be used by a task scheduler thread to somehow optimize the queuing? Or is the point just to allow you to write code linearly and then put those yields in it to break it up? In which case it wouldn't be useful for me if I already had my jobs split up into separate tasks by design?

**Question 4:** Am I trying to reinvent the wheel here? Has this problem already been solved? And if so, why are there so many different implementations?

Comment: Pose a non-trivial problem to N programmers and you'll be lucky to get only N solutions.

Comment: Just an answer to whether coroutines have anything to do with my problem would be helpful :)

Comment: You can't really generalize that much IMO, as it all depends on use-case. With good requirements and analysis of them, together with a good design, and it should hopefully limit the number of choices.

Comment: Each of my questions are specific ;) The problem overall is general. That's why I made it clear what my questions are. If you like, just consider the rest of it as context.

Comment: Nothing needs coroutines but they can offer clean solutions to various problems. Few uses: Infinite sequences, functions that return values from a sequence each time they are called (getNextX() kind of thing), and functions that execute a multi-step process over multiple invocations (each invocation may or may not be a new step). The state management of the multi-step process can be managed within the coroutine.

Comment: I have tried to interpret the question post as a not-**too-broad** question, but I have failed. Do you want us to answer your "Question X"? - Four questions are definitely too broad. Do you want us to suggest a way concurrently execute job `abc`? - A lot of possible solutions and no details (restrictions) about the problem. Have I missed something?

Comment: Question 1 was: "doesn't (1) have the same blocking problem?" Question 2: "is this what co-routines are useful for?" If the answer is "no" that's awesome!

These are specific questions. I'm not asking you to try to interpret a question out of the broad context given. I literally asked specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:  No, it more likely has a different blocking problem.

Q2:  Co-routines have many applications; try substituting for X in "is this what X is for?"  X = { while, if, return, pointer, ... }.  Don't look to standards bodies (particularly that one) for insight; they are best at punctuation and spell checking.

Q3:  Co-routines can be used to optimise various constructions, but the real goal of using such a formalism is to make your program as natural an expression of the problem as possible.  One of the better examples of how Co-routines can be intelligently used are the Go-routines of Go.

Q4:  Probably; almost definitely; because many of the solutions are inadequate.

Q1+Q4.  There is no single blocking problem, some that come to mind are: Deadlock, Livelock, unnecessarily sequential, non-Scalable, Slow.  Some structures {{ threads, coroutines, threads + coroutines } * { locks, conditions, message passing }} help solve some of these problems, but induce others.  My favourite is { (threads + coroutines) * (message passing) }, which is typically good for everything but Slow.